Avoid Having To Use CORS Or x-google-endpoints In Cloud Endpoints?
So I am having a very frustrating problem that I have been trying to solve for 2 days. I am not able to create a second version of our API because in order to call my cloud run endpoints cors needs to be set in GCP Cloud Endpoints like so:
x-google-endpoints:
  - name: gateway-url
    allowCors: true

However I cannot deploy this to two separate endpoint files, for example:
Version 1
swagger: '2.0'
host: gateway-url
x-google-endpoints:
  - name: gateway-url
    allowCors: true
info:
  title: Title
  description: Description
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
consumes:
  - application/json
basePath: /v1

Version 2
swagger: '2.0'
host: gateway-url
x-google-endpoints:
  - name: gateway-url
    allowCors: true
info:
  title: Title
  description: Description
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
consumes:
  - application/json
basePath: /v2

As you can see above I have 2 gateway files and I create a different gateway file for each version. However when I create anything more than a single cloud endpoints file I get the following error:
OpenAPI spec is invalid. Multiple endpoint entries are defined in the extension \'x-google-endpoints\'. At most one entry is allowed.

I have tried many different things including taking the x-google-endpoints code out of my Endpoints file but when I do I lose control over CORS and can no longer handle it in cloud run.
My original cloud run file looked like this:
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();
const routes = require('./routes');
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
}

router.options('/', cors(corsOptions));

...

This did not work. Even after completely removing CORS from my Cloud Run service and trying to manually handle it like this:
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return res.status(204).send('');
    }
    next();
});

I was still not able to call the endpoint. I have even tried adding options requests to the cloud endpoints YAML file and this still does not work.
options:
  summary: CORS Preflight
  description: Handle CORS preflight requests
  operationId: cors_preflight
  x-google-backend:
    address: https://my-cloud-run-service
  responses:
    '204':
      description: No Content

So my question is, is there any way to either:

Handle CORS without using x-google-endpoints in the Endpoints YAML file?
Handle CORS in my cloud run service without having to set it in Endpoints?
Something else that Im missing that will easily get me past this?

BTW, I do know that a similar question was asked in 2019 here,  But it was never really answered.
Using x-google-endpoints OpenAPI extension with multiple API versions in Cloud Endpoints
I cannot see versioning an API to be a niche use case and for this not to be handled is pretty counterintuitive on Googles side, so Im sure I have to be missing something. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I've only used Cloud Endpoints with gRPC services and not Swagger. Before reading @wayne-zhang;s answers to the other question, I was going to propose that you need to unify /v1 and /v2 into a single service config to have any chance of getting this to work. Is this your intent to run both API versions concurrently? If so, I think you should take a look at Wayne's suggestions. He's one of the engineers on Cloud Endpoints and, in my experience, knows what he's talking about.

Actually I found out that you CAN run both versions concurrently and do not have to merge both v1 and v2. This would not be suitable for us as we plan to have more than 2 versions of the API and it will be prone to bugs if we are looking to compile these into one larger file or it will get very messy if we just combine them into one bigger file and try to work off of that.

So what I did find is that you can include x-google-endpoints in the latest version ONLY and it will work for any previous version of the API. However for some reason when I tried this the first time it didn't seem to be working (probably an error on my part). After reconfiguring and trying again the x-google-endpoints now work for all versions of endpoints.
